# Future builder flutter firebase error: A value of type 'Iterable<BlogPost>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<BlogPost>'

Tags: list, firebase, flutter, future, flutter-futurebuilder

I am having an issue with creating a future builder. I am trying to create a List of Documents to show in a ListView but I can not find away to create the List in the custom class I have created(BlogPosts).

I keep receiving this error:

```
Error: A value of type 'Iterable<BlogPost>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<BlogPost>'.
```

here is my code:

```
CollectionReference postsRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts');
late List<BlogPost> posts;

FutureBuilder(
          future: postsRef.get().then((val) {
              posts = val.docs.map((doc) => BlogPost.fromDocument(doc));
            }),
          builder: (context, snap) {
            if(snap.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return ListView.builder(
                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: 3,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Text('data);
                  }
              );
            } else {
              return Center(
                child: Text('Loading')
              );
            }
          }
        )
```

here is the code for my custom class:

```
class BlogPost {
  String displayName;
  String postmsg;
  String postId;
  String UserId;

  BlogPost(this.displayName, this.postmsg, this.postId, this.UserId);

  factory BlogPost.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return BlogPost(
        doc['displayName'],
        doc['postmsg'],
        doc['postId'],
        doc['UserId']
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`map()` function](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) returns an `Iterable`. To turn that into a list, call `toList()` on its result. So:

```
posts = val.docs.map((doc) => BlogPost.fromDocument(doc)).toList()
```

Comment: I no longer have that error but now when trying to use 'post' I'm getting the error "LateInitializationError: Field 'posts' has not been initialized." any idea how to fix this?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to access `posts` before you've given it a value. The stack trace of the error should tell you exactly where the problem occurs.